# How to use encodeURI against variable in Tranform

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to create a transform where I call [encodeURI](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-url-functions-encodeuri) against a variable as follows.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::URL
output application/json
---
{
    "encodeURI" : encodeURI(#[vars.myVar])
}
```

But this case following error.

> Invalid input '#', expected ??? or booleanNotExpr (line 6, column 29):

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: you don't need the #[  ] inside a DW script. Just use `encodeURI(vars.myVar)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already inside DW script you do not need to wrap it to DW script again. Remove #[] and it will work fine.

https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/EncodeSpecialCharacters.html